# On clicking on a search field my desktop theme changes?

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page which has a list of all objects and have attached it to a input field tag , so it can autocomplete my search ... but when i click the input field , my window refreshes and my desktop theme gets changed to Basic windows 8 theme.This happens somethings and not always. Can someone tell me why this is happening ? My list of objects is very large could that be the answer..
Please help.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I don't think Salesforce or any VF page can change your PC theme. It may be some other program running in background is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that visual-force can change your desktop theme however since you mentioned that you have a large number of objects, it may happen that your system is low on memory due to browser requiring more memory to perform calculations and it disables Aero theme temporarily.

You can try some other system with larger RAM size (4 GB or 8 GB) and see if it replicates.

Also check if you are doing some large computation on click of you `apex:inputField`.